# Javascript with leaflet- javascript code doesnt work without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

I am working on javascript and leaflet maps to create something like this: I have a map on screen and on the map should be multiple polygons in the shape of arrows to rotate as per the changing data on map. The problem is the javascript works fine when I add an alert in the javascript but if not then the arrows just show up on screen on the last location, there is no motion in this case. I tried to put the code inside window.onload but it still doesnt work. It only works if i have a alert.

The data input is from a json file. 
Additionally i didn't have this issue before i started using leaflet multipolygon instead of geojson polygon.

Below is my code. I can provide any other details needed.
Thanks for the help!

```
window.onload = function () {

var cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/4fd891040a8a4ecb805c388019e23d46/64082/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

var basemap = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 18});
var latlng = new L.LatLng(30, -88);
var delay = 350;        // animation delay (larger is slower)
var Npoints;        // number of points per track
var isRunning = true;
var multiPolygon = [];
var pts =[];
var arrowSize = [];
var arrowAngle = [];
var arrowsDataMap = new Map();
var pointLength;
var arrowLength;

function showTimeStep(p) {
    var point = [];
    var latLngPoints = [];

    //for loop to create one layer of multipolygons
    for (var j = 0; j < arrowLength; j++) {
        alert(arrowLength);
        for (var m = 0; m < pointLength; m++) {     
            if(j>0)
                map.removeLayer(multiP);

            parts.push(0.00);
            //some code to create polygon
            parts.push(0.00+size/3);

            var combined = parts.join(" ");
            var a = combined.split(":");
            var ans = [];
            for(var k=0;k<a.length;k++){
                var latLong = a[k].split(",");
                ans.push([ parseFloat(latLong[0]), parseFloat(latLong[1]) ]);
            }

            domain = {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ans]}; 

            var sine = Math.sin(-angle);
            var cos = Math.cos(-angle);

            for (var i=0;i<ans.length;i++){
                var px=ans[i][0];
                var py=ans[i][1];

                //rotate
                var xnew = (px*cos)-(py*sine);
                var ynew = (px*sine)+(py*cos);

                //translate
                px=((xnew+latLngPoint[0]));
                py=((ynew+latLngPoint[1]));
                ans[i][0]=px;
                ans[i][1]=py;

                //polygon
                point[i] = L.latLng(py,px);
            }
            //Array of multipolygons
            multiPolygon[m] = point;
        }

        var multiP = L.multiPolygon(multiPolygon);
        map.addLayer(multiP); //Plotting polygon on the map

        if (p == arrowLength) {
            nextp = (p + 1) % Npoints;
            setTimeout(function(i) {
                return function() {
                    showTimeStep(i);
                }
            }(nextp), delay);
        }
    }
}

//function to load data from json file and create map
function animateLines(data) {
    pointLength = data.points.length;
    arrowLength = data.points["0"].point.length;

    for (var viewEntryKey in data.points) {
        var arrowsMap = new Map();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.points[viewEntryKey].point.length; i++) {
            var arrowMap = new Map();

            arrowMap.set(1,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].latLng);
            arrowMap.set(2,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].size);
            arrowMap.set(3,data.points[viewEntryKey].point[i].angle);

            arrowsMap.set(i,arrowMap);
        }

        arrowsDataMap.set(viewEntryKey,arrowsMap);
    }

    showTimeStep(0);
}

var tracks = L.layerGroup([])
var map = new L.Map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 7, layers: [basemap, tracks]});
map.addControl(new MyButton({layer: tracks}));

var tracklines = null;

//json file holding data
var url1 = "pointsData.json";
$.getJSON(url1, function(mydata) {
    tracklines = mydata;
    //$.each(mydata.points.point,function(index,value){ alert(value.size);})
})
.fail(function(xhr, statustext) { 
    tracklines = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText.replace(/NaN/g,'null'));
})
.done(function() {
    // assume all lines have the same number of points
    Npoints = 301;
    animateLines(tracklines);
});
};
```

Json(Its a little crude as the data is being duplicated and can be structured better):

```
     {
  "points": [
  {
    "point": [
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.79"
      },
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.69"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-88.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.49"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "point": [
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.79"
      },
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.69"
      }
      ,
      {
        "latLng": [-89.9999988477954, 29.999999681521295],
        "size": "0.15",
        "angle": "0.49"
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Based on what you describe, I'd say you have a race condition between asynchronous requests.

Comment: The code is not formatted properly - too hard to read, sorry.

Comment: @Mathletics Okay..Thanks for the help. I will try looking up race conditions. (I am fairly inexperienced at javascript so I am a little clueless about the race condition!)

Comment: @hgoebl ..I am sorry about that. I will re-post it again with better formatting.

Comment: Hi @hgoebl, I have tried to better format and comment my code. Please do let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the cause of the problem is. But ...

- always use `console.log` and not `alert()`

`alert` is changing the timing of your code drastically, while `console.log` should be more-or-less neutral.

First you have to find out whether the timing/async problem is caused by JSON loading or by your `setTimeout` calls. You could remove `alert` and place some console log messages, run the program and analyze the output. Play around with `delay`, e.g. set it to 3 seconds or 3 millis and see how the behaviour changes.

BTW it doesn't look like you're unexperienced in JavaScript, e.g. you didn't make the mistake to create functions in a loop, but wrapped it with an anonymous function - well done! As I don't know the structure of your JSON data, maybe I'm wrong, but accessing the points with Strings like "0" looks a bit like it is actually an array and then I would treat is an an array (see `for (var viewEntryKey in data.points)`). Just a thought which might be wrong...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try out the things you suggested. I'll also put up the structure of the json to make looking at the code easier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with running two for loops. The loop "for (var j = 0; j < arrowLength; j++)" was actually not required and was the one creating issue.